# Age of the first universe according eternal inflation model

Tags: matter

In the eternal inflation our universe has the approximate age of 13.7 billion years.the question is; what's the age of the first universe that was made according this theory ?thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that no-one knows.

There are some general arguments that eternal inflation must have started a finite time ago i.e. eternal inflation can't have been going on forever. These are described in section 6 of Alan Guth's paper [Eternal inflation and its implications](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0702178), but the arguments are a bit technical and I'm not sure how easy they it would be to present them in a simplified way here.

Anyhow, there is currently no theory to describe when and how eternal inflation got started, so we have no idea when the first bubble universe nucleated.

Comment: I wonder if we could calculate the passing of time( outside ) our universe (in the false vacuum ) in any meaningful way ?dose it looks like inside the event horizon of a black hole ?